# SQL: Problems combining several rows and columns to single row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

First time poster, long time lurker, here.

I am having some problems making a query work (SQL Server). I am collecting transaction data from several tables, joining them together and am supposed to combine rows to singles ones when they have values in certain fields and share the same id (`paymentid`, see below).

This query is collecting data from several tables:

```
select 
   dt.transid, dt.accountingdate, dp.paymentdate, dp.paidamount, 
   (case when dt.amounttypeid = 1 then dt.transamount else 0 end) 'capital',
   (case when dt.amounttypeid = 2 then dt.transamount else 0 end) 'interest',
   dp.paymentid
from 
   dat_trans dt            
join 
   cfg_amounttype_desc cad on dt.amounttypeid = cad.amounttypeid
join 
   cfg_transtype_desc ctd on dt.transtypeid = ctd.transtypeid                
join 
   dat_payment dp on dp.paymentid = dt.paymentid               
where 
   dt.transamount > 0 and dt.paymentid in (4,6,7)
   and dt.transtypeid in (4,16, 42, 90, 121, 128, 129)
```

and results in (row groups separated for visibility here):

```
transid     accountingdate  paymentdate     paidamount  capital   interest    paymentid
1           2014-02-01      2014-01-01      2000        1600      0           1
2           2014-02-01      2014-01-01      2000        0         200         1        
3           2014-02-01      2014-01-01      2000        200       0           1

4           2014-03-02      2014-02-01      1800        1600      0           2
5           2014-03-02      2014-02-01      1800        0         0           2        
6           2014-03-02      2014-02-01      1800        200       0           2

7           2014-04-03      2014-03-01      600         0         100         3
8           2014-04-03      2014-03-01      600         0         0           3        
9           2014-04-03      2014-03-01      600         500       0           3
```

My aim is to combine the data in columns, capital and interest like this:

```
accountingdate  paymentdate     paidamount  capital   interest    paymentid
2014-02-01      2014-01-01      2000        1800      200         1
2014-03-02      2014-02-01      1800        1700                  2
2014-04-03      2014-03-01      600         500       100         3
```

-- (transid left out here, its only used for testing) and will be excluded in the final result.

I've tried to sum up *capital* and *interest* by using examples found on this site (union, pivot/unpivot, cte's) but my result looks something like below:

```
accountingdate  paymentdate     paidamount  capital   interest    paymentid
2014-02-01      2014-01-01      2000        1800                  1
2014-02-01      2014-01-01      2000                  200         1
```

That is, the capital do add up but there's still two rows instead of one.

So, basically I am trying to create one row per payment, and sum up the amounts in the several columns (and additional columns that will be added later like fee information for each payment). I appreciate any suggestion that would help me solve this. I hope I've included all information needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hard to see with out the grouping query but it would appear you are grouping by transid, but not selecting it?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment. There is no grouping specified yet in this query, the above is what I use now and the result is from that whole question, transid is selected (first one after select).

Comment: Now I'm confused Select accountingdate,payamentdate,payment_id, sum(ifnull(paidamount,0)) as paidamount, sum blah blah blah) From SomeTable Group by (accountingdate,paymentdate, payments_id) Doesn't work?

Comment: The results you're expecting make no sense. Where does the 1700 cpatial come from for paymentid 2? Is the paidamount always the same for every row of a given paymentid?

Comment: I apologise if I was a bit unclear. The capital and interest is included in a group of costs that will/can be included later such as fees and administrative costs. So, basically paidamount = (capital+interest+fees+admin_costs). The paidamount is always the same for a given paymentid.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select paymentid, accountingdate, paymentdate,
       sum(paidamount) paidamount,
       sum(capital) capital,
       sum(interest) interest
from (
      select 
         dt.transid, dt.accountingdate, dp.paymentdate, dp.paidamount, 
         (case when dt.amounttypeid = 1 then dt.transamount else 0 end) 'capital',
         (case when dt.amounttypeid = 2 then dt.transamount else 0 end) 'interest',
         dp.paymentid
      from 
         dat_trans dt            
      join 
         cfg_amounttype_desc cad on dt.amounttypeid = cad.amounttypeid
      join 
         cfg_transtype_desc ctd on dt.transtypeid = ctd.transtypeid                
      join 
         dat_payment dp on dp.paymentid = dt.paymentid               
      where 
         dt.transamount > 0 and dt.paymentid in (4,6,7)
         and dt.transtypeid in (4,16, 42, 90, 121, 128, 129)
      )
group by paymentid, accountingdate, paymentdate
```

or

```
select 
   dt.accountingdate, dp.paymentdate, 
   sum(dp.paidamount) paidamount, 
   sum((case when dt.amounttypeid = 1 then dt.transamount else 0 end)) capital,
   sum((case when dt.amounttypeid = 2 then dt.transamount else 0 end)) interest,
   dp.paymentid
from 
   dat_trans dt            
join 
   cfg_amounttype_desc cad on dt.amounttypeid = cad.amounttypeid
join 
   cfg_transtype_desc ctd on dt.transtypeid = ctd.transtypeid                
join 
   dat_payment dp on dp.paymentid = dt.paymentid               
where 
   dt.transamount > 0 and dt.paymentid in (4,6,7)
   and dt.transtypeid in (4,16, 42, 90, 121, 128, 129)
group by dt.accountingdate, dp.paymentdate, dp.paymentid
```